# Find by ID in KnockOutJS

Tags: knockout.js

Given the following, how do I get id 10 back out?

```
function ChildListViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray([]);   

    self.children.push({id:20,name:"Jake"});
    self.children.push({id:10,name:"Jake"});

    self.find = function(id)
    {   
        console.log(self.children().length);
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(self.children().length);}, 500);
        found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.children(), function(child) {
            return child.id() === id;
        });

        console.log(found);

        return found;
    }

}
```

I want to do something like

```
ChildVM.find(10);
```

All attempts using `ko.utils.arrayFirst` and `ko.utils.arrayForEach` have failed me.

**EDIT**

This now works, see selected answers.

Issues around loading order and AJAX meant this was not working as it should do.

Comment: arrayFirst should work, how are you using it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.children(), function(child) {
    return child.id === id;
});
```

Just remember to use `self.children()` to get to the underlying array.

Comment: Doesn't that return `true` though - rather than the child object?

Comment: It returns the object that matches the condition.

Comment: @jakenoble the parameter function (or closure if you like) passed to the arrayFirst function return *true* to identify items that match the desired criteria (in this case, "id" identity) - the arrayFirst function, based on the result of the closure, return the first item that matches.

Comment: I have updated my question. `found` is always null. And also  `.length` is zero. But in the `setTimeout` it is three. I think, because my data is loading via AJAX it is causing ordering issues?

Comment: Right this works, but I have bigger issues now about how my page loads. Thanks RP Niemeyer.